# Intellij Load Settings error

Tags: intellij-idea

After a computer crash i get the following error in Intellij:

```
Cannot load settings from file 'C:\Users\*\.IdeaIC14\config\options\mavenVersion.xml': content truncated
        File content will be recreated
```

What I've tried to no success: clearing `\caches` folder, deleting `mavenVersion.xml` file.

Please help restoring peace in Intellij IDEA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, there were Intellij and Android Studio installed on my machine.

I deleted the .idea dir in the project. Opened the project in Android Studio. Closed it. Then everything was fine in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

I am pasting the contents of my `mavenVerison.xml` file for you - please recreate the file with this contents, in the specified location, and give it another try.

```
<application>
  <component name="MavenVersion" version="3.x" vmOptions="-Xmx512m" embedderJdk="#JAVA_INTERNAL" />
</application>
```

Note that I am using maven 3.x.

If this doesn't work, and if you don't mind reconfiguring your environment again, stop IntelliJ, move the entire .IdeaIC14 folder to some place else, and restart IntelliJ.